# Enclosing an attached carport w/ concrete slab. The slab is not completely level. Pour concrete over existing floor or install wooden subfloor?

Tags: subfloor, self-leveling-concrete, leveling

I am assuming my location may matter on this topic. We live in north Texas north of Dallas approximately an hour.

We are enclosing an attached carport w/ concrete slab foundation. The slab is not completely level. I have lived here for 3.5 years. I have never seen any moisture or condensation on the slab no matter what the weather conditions.

The enclosure will be 22'x24' the far corner is approximately 1.5" lower than the opposite corner.

I need to level the floor as this is going to be the new living area.

Do I pour concrete over existing floor or install wooden sub-floor?

Comment: 1.5" over 20'   is not significant, can you live with it? How high is the ceiling, how much space do you have to work with if you add a wood sub-floor.

Comment: The east and west walls are 10' and the north wall at the center of the vaulted area is 12'. You are right and it really isn't that noticeable to be honest.

Comment: I have a 13 X13  covered patio with about 1" of pitch for drainage . I enclosed it without  any consideration of the pitch. I actually forgot it was there until I read this.

Answer (score 2):

Comfort is generally better with a wooden subfloor, if you have the room for a wooden subfloor. That also allows adding insulation to reduce the heating/air conditioning load (which may be minimal from the floor, given your location.)

Plenty of old houses have floors that slope a lot worse than 1.5" in 20 ft (0.67% if I got the math right) and they work as living space, so not "fixing" it at all as Alaska Man comments is certainly an option, particularly if it's an "even" slope.

*i.e.* any properly built porch has 1% to 2% slope and most people are unaware of that.